# Slow requests between AWS Elastic Beanstalk and S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm experiencing slow requests between an elastic beanstalk application and S3, both in the same region. A simple get operation on a 20 byte file consistently takes between 2020ms and 2060ms, and other operations are also similarly slow. I'm guessing there's a 2000ms timeout somewhere followed by a successful request, but can't figure out where.

The the code has been tested on both a deprecated beanstalk running Docker on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.15.0, and a newer version running 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.11.

Request metrics on the bucket looks healthy, with latency averaging around 40ms. There's only a few hundred small files in the bucket and a couple of requests per second at most, so we're nowhere near the limits where S3 start throttling requests.

The code is quite straight forward:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();

var client = S3Client.builder().build();

var request = GetObjectRequest.builder().key(key).bucket(bucket).build();

ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> responseStream = client.getObjectAsBytes(request);

var response = new String(responseStream.asByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

long elapsedMilliseconds = stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
LOGGER.info("getObject took {} ms for key {}", elapsedMilliseconds, key);
        
return response;
```

Any tips on further debugging?

Comment: Where is the S3 bucket located? Where is your Elasticbeanstalk application located? Is it a cross region request? How big is the file? What is the logger.info output here?

Comment: Everything is located in eu-north-1, it's not a cross region request. The file is 20 bytes.
The output is `getObject took 2040 ms for key foobar/foobar.txt`.

Comment: Initialise `client` once in your class and then make the same request 3 times - do all 3 requests take 2 seconds or does only the first one take 2 seconds?

Comment: Yes, all consecutive requests also take 2 seconds.

Comment: Does getting the file locally via the CLI also take 2 seconds? What is the networking configuration of your EB application? Where are you starting the stopwatch? Can you start and stop it right before and after `getObjectAsBytes`? Is it still 2 seconds? There must be something up with either the S3 bucket or the EB application. Is the S3 file encrypted?